# JQuery Ajax to retrieve JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to retrieve the 8 latest images from flickr API using jQuery, but I'm kinda a noob to jquery ajax and JSON

I'm using .ajax to retrieve the info and the .each method to loop and parse the response, then append to my document in a div "#flickr"

I think this is pretty simple for a lot of people, but like I said, i'm just learning.. here's what I have..

```
   $.ajax({
url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=nature&format=json&jsoncallback",
type: "GET",
cache: true,
dataType:'jsonp',
success: function (response) {display(response)           
} 
 });

 var display = function(response) {
  .each(response , function(){
  $('#flickr').append()
})
});
```

#### Edit

```
  var flickr = function(){
    $.ajax({ 
    type:"GET",
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=nature&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
             displayflickr(response)} 
                });
            };

var displayflickr = function(response){
     $.each(response, function(i, item) {
     $('#flickr').append(item);
               });
  }
```

It's not doing anything at all. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $.each(response , function(index,value){
  $('#flickr').append(response [index])
})
```

or

```
   $.each(response , function(index,value){
    $('#flickr').append(value);
   })
```